Do CSS variables work inside of a template or custom element?
I'm building a small website using web components written in pure HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Everything is working well except for the CSS variable that I want to use. Here is the stylesheet:
 :root { 
    --bh-color-1:#8f1010;
  }
  .bh-action {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:whitesmoke;
    background-color:var(--bh-color-1);
    height:32px;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }

Is there a problem with the syntax? This is from DevTools:
<bh-feature>
            <header slot="header">
              <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>
Sharpening Service</header>
            <p slot="content">yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada</p>
            <a href="#" slot="action" class="bh-action">Get Started</a>
        </bh-feature>

You can see that the bh-action class from the stylesheet is set on an <a> element which is inside a custom element.
Also from DevTools:
.bh-action {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: var(--bh-color-1);
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

You can see that the style has been applied to the <a> element, but the variable hasn't been resolved to a value. Everything else works as expected, including the color if I use the numbers directly. The entire stylesheet is imported into the template, including the variable declaration. So far I've tried putting the variable and class declarations in the style tag of the template and wrapping the variable in curly braces, like var({--bh-color-1}) and var({{bh-color-1 }}).
Is there a way to make this work or is it an issue?

Have you tried wrapping the initial css variable value in quotes?
:root { --bh-color-1:"#8f1010;"}

Your issue is actually with the :root { selector: you can't target elements in the light DOM from the shadow DOM.
The :root pseudo-class in an HTML document will point to the <html> element, which does live in the light DOM and which you thus can't target from the shadow-DOM.

Either you move the css-variable declaration in the light-DOM, if you really want it to apply on the <html> and be inherited by all its (shadow-including) descendants,



<style>
  span {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--color);
  }
  /* Defined in Light DOM, applies to everyone, even shadow DOM */
  :root {
    --color: red;
  }
</style>
<host-element>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <style>
      span {
        color: var(--color);
      }
    </style>
    <span>Shadow: color me</span>
  </template>
</host-element>
<span>Light: My border color is also affected</span>




Either you use the :host pseudo-class (or function) so that only all your shadow-descendants inherit it.



<style>
  span {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--color);
  }
</style>
<host-element>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <style>
      /* Defined in Shadow DOM, applies only to descendants */
      :host {
        --color: red;
      }
      span {
        color: var(--color);
      }
    </style>
    <span>Shadow: color me</span>
  </template>
</host-element>
<span>Light: My border is not colored anymore</span>



(Note that setting the css-variable on the actual host element from the light DOM would "win" over the shadow-defined :host rule.)


<style>
  /* direct rules from light wins over :host */
  target-element {
    --color: green;
  }
  /* but inheritance loses */
  :root {
    --color: yellow;
  }
</style>
<target-element>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <style>
      :host {
        --color: red;
      }
      span {
        color: var(--color);
      }
    </style>
    <span>Shadow targeted by light</span>
  </template>
</target-element>

<inheriting-element>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <style>
      :host {
        --color: red;
      }
      span {
        color: var(--color);
      }
    </style>
    <span>Shadow inheriting</span>
  </template>
</inheriting-element>




This is a great answer. Thanks very much for clearing this up.
